# Is it possible to show output by test method in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, junit, continuous-integration

I find gradle has already supported showing output by test class. It's quite useful for debugging when test fails on Continuous Integration Server.
I'm wondering is there a way to show output by method instead of class which will be even better. Sometimes, a test class has many test methods which makes the output still hard to inspect.

[image]

[image]

Comment: currently this is not supported by gradle. but it is on the long list of things we want to do as you can see in the according design document:  https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/design-docs/testing-improvements.md#story-html-test-report-shows-output-per-test

Comment: Thanks for the link @ReneGroeschke